# How to use @JsonPropertyOrder annotation in beans.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, sap-commerce-cloud

I want to order my Data transfer object(POJO) created using beans.xml. can someone please tell me how to use @JsonPropertyOrder annotation in xml file rather than in Java?

Thanks much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the annotations element, like this:

```
<bean class="de.hybris.platform.couponfacades.data.AnnotatedPojo">

    <import type="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement"/>
    <import type="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElements"/>
    <import type="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement"/>

    <annotations>@XmlRootElement</annotations>

    <property name="someText" type="String">

        <annotations scope="getter">
        @XmlElements(value = {
                @XmlElement(name="map",
                    type=ValueAsMap.class),
                @XmlElement(name="string",
                    type=ValueAsString.class)
        })
        </annotations>

    </property>

</bean>
```

**Other reference:**

- Generating Beans and Enums: https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/8bc53579866910149472ccbef0222ec5.html